# Vector bitwise and with constant value on GCC

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors

Is the following test case valid for gcc?

```
typedef signed char v16signed_char __attribute__ ((__vector_size__ (sizeof(signed char) * 16)));
v16signed_char and_imm(v16signed_char a)
{
    v16signed_char s = a & 0xFF;
    return s;
}
```

It fails on gcc, apparently because 0xFF is too large. Should it fail? By failure I mean compiler error:

```
error: conversion of scalar ‘int’ to vector ‘v4unsigned_int {aka __vector(4) signed char}’ involves truncation
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it fails"? What do you mean by "valid"? Please make your question clearer and explain your expected/desired results in detail.

Comment: I edited the question thanks!

Comment: Cool. Did you read https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html?

Comment: I suupose you refer at "For convenience, it is allowed to use a binary vector operation where one operand is a scalar. In that case the compiler transforms the scalar operand into a vector where each element is the scalar from the operation. The transformation happens only if the scalar could be safely converted to the vector-element type. ". Why 0xFF could not be converted to a char?

Comment: I'm still reading it tbh but I was wondering whether you'd already ruled it out as a source of the answer (would save me some time :P)

Answer (score 0):

The operation `&` itself is valid, fortunately: *[[ref](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html)]*

> The types defined in this manner can be used with a subset of normal C operations. Currently, GCC allows using the following operators on these types: `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `unary minus`, `^`, `|`, `&`, `~`, `%`.

However, it seems that you need to provide an operand of the base type.

`0xFF` is an `int`, but your base type is `signed char`.

So:

```
v16signed_char s = a & (signed char)0xFF;
```

The documentation says:

> For convenience, it is allowed to use a binary vector operation where one operand is a scalar. In that case the compiler transforms the scalar operand into a vector where each element is the scalar from the operation. The transformation happens only if the scalar could be safely converted to the vector-element type.

Without a definition of "could be safely converted", I'm not sure I can say with confidence whether your original code is *supposed* to compile under these rules. However, I suspect they've taken a strict approach here since an arbitrary `int`→`signed char` conversion can lose data.

It *may* be (or be related to) [bug 53784](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53784). Or it may be expected.

Though it's interesting, because in the case of this literal that's clearly not the case, and in non-vectorised code you would expect the usual warning to be elided in situations like this for that reason.

Comment: I think any more concrete answer will have to come from GCC devs. Fortunately there are a few lurking around these parts so hold your breath.

Comment: The scalar must have the same type as the base type of the vector. Bizarrely there seems to be no way to create a vector with n identical items but s * (signed char) 0 + (signed char) n produces optimal code, ignoring s and not multiplying or adding.